# If the inner join value is null then i want to execute a query if it is not execute another query using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

If the inner join value is null, then I want to execute a query; if it is not, execute another query using a stored procedure

```
SELECT 
    City.City, Country.Country_Name, Branch_Master.Br_Code 
FROM
    Branch_Master 
INNER JOIN
    Country ON Country.Country_ID = Branch_Master.Country_ID  
INNER JOIN
    City ON City.CityCode = Branch_Master.CityCode 
WHERE
    Branch_Master. DeleteFlag = '1'
```

If `Branch_Master.Country_ID` is null, then I want to execute a query

```
select * from Branch_Master
```

If it is not null, then execute the above query

Comment: Have you tried switching to `left join`?

Comment: use `if exists( some query) begin -- query you wish to execute if your condition is fulfilled end else -- other query`

Comment: You would need to use a programming construct like `if`.  Your two queries seem to return different sets of columns.

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope this will work for you

**SOLUTION 1**

```
if Exists(Select 1 from Branch_Master bm where bm.Country_ID IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN
Select City.City, Country.Country_Name,Branch_Master.Br_Code 
from Branch_Master 
inner join Country on Country.Country_ID=Branch_Master.Country_ID  
inner join City on City.CityCode=Branch_Master.CityCode 
where  Branch_Master. DeleteFlag='1'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 select * from Branch_Master bm
END
```

**SOLUTION 2**
You may also use left join to achieve your required data.

```
Select ISNULL(City.City,'--') AS City, 
ISNULL(Country.Country_Name,'--') AS Country_Name,
ISNULL(Branch_Master.Br_Code,'--') AS Br_Code 
from Branch_Master 
left join Country on Country.Country_ID=Branch_Master.Country_ID  
left join City on City.CityCode=Branch_Master.CityCode 
where  Branch_Master. DeleteFlag='1'
```

Comment: @neetha mathew try this answer